# what is the v1 folder about in TFX

Tags: tfx

I'm new to [TFX](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/tfx) and a bit confused about what the [`v1`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/tfx/v1) about, and what is its relationship with the code outside `v1`?

Do I understand correctly that the official APIs are in `v1`, meaning I should always do

```
import tfx.v1.something
```

instead of just

```
import tfx.something
```

Comment: `tfx.v1` is a public API from `TFX` which is designed to have similar notation as that of `TensorFlow`, where if we `import tfx.v1 as tfx` once, We can use any function `tfx.a.b.c` instead of doing `from tfx.a.b import c` separately every single time. Thanks!